# showing pop up dialog box

Tags: java, swing

hii
I want show a pop up Dialog box when i click on to button

Explanation:

Actually i m creating a program in which i send a mail to email id
I want to take email address to send mail
for that I want a pop up dialog which ask me to type email valid address
after that i want to take that email address from that dialog box for send mail

Comment: you just need to click the tick next to the answer to accept it, not that hard and encourages more people to answer your questions in the future

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080205/popup-message-boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JOptionPane for that

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input

Comment: thanks a lot......                                        


 
i ve used      "JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter valid emaiId");"

but now i want to perform some action  on   that "email id"

Comment: showInputDialog returns the value entered by the user so you can use
String emailId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...