# Can't extract some javafx directories from my java jdk folder

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a team building a project of with javafx and I have an error on my javafx.scene.control.Alert import. Has it been deprecated?

I see that there are still compressed folders in my jdk folder, which contain javafx directories, and give me the error "unable to create the specified directory: ensure that the directory does not already exist." (It doesn't). Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794987/what-is-replacement-of-alert-in-javafx-2-1-alert-is-in-javafx-1-3-but-not-in-j

Comment: `Alert` was introduced in Java 8 update 40. Make sure you are using that version.