# Decorate a Popup menu

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have been using Java8 and controlsfx to create pop ups. But it is incompatible with my other plugin i have designed. I have been forced to go back to 7 and use Popup.  Popup has no background or border when created.  Is it possible to give it a background and border? Something emulate the controlsfx popup?

Comment: Maybe you should ask how to make your other plugin compatible instead?

Comment: It appears that eclipseFX does not play nice with JRE8.

Comment: I am using efxclipse, but have not noticed show stopping issues. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When I run my application I seem to run into noclassfound errors. I have added the correct jars into my plugin build path. Also I have done some research and found that FXCanvas has been moved to another jar. So I had added that to the buildpath.  After fixing the canvas problem. It has problems finding javafx.scene.parent now.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Yes, indeed, it is possible to give a background and border to popup ! The emulate the `controlsfx popup effect` you will have to work hard.

For a simple popup, with border and background, look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18687993/1759128