# Java FX system tray message

Tags: javafx, popup, awt, system-tray

I'm developping an application that needs to run silently in the system tray.

That's why i used this [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626550/to-hide-javafx-fxml-or-javafx-swing-application-to-system-tray) first to hide my application in the System Tray, which is working really nicely.

However at some point my users will need to be notified about things. Like on Skype or Msn, when you get a message you are being notified of it with a popup in the right bottom zone of your display.

I'm looking for a way to reproduce this, i couldn't find anything in the **java.awt.SystemTray** doc. Is there any native class doing this or should i try to reproduce it by generating a window myself ?

Comment: Correct answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12571924/1624376)

Answer (score 1):

First there is the answer from [JavaFX: what is the best way to display a simple message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669209/javafx-what-is-the-best-way-to-display-a-simple-message). This uses a custom popup as javafx from java 8 could not be used by the implementor.

If you can use javafx2 (the one with java 8) you can look at the Controlsfx library found here: [Notifications with Controlsfx](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#notifications)