# JOptionPane in JavaFX?

Tags: java

Can we use a `JOptionPane` in JavaFX? If yes, then how?

Is there a way that I can popup a message via a dialog box in a JavaFX program as I can do through `javax.swing` with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`? If not, is there any other alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and show common dialog (Error, Warning, Confirmation) in JavaFX 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309981/how-to-create-and-show-common-dialog-error-warning-confirmation-in-javafx-2)

Answer (score 0):

From Cay Horstmann's new book Java SE8 for the Really Impatient (Pearson 2014), s. 4.2, he outlines using

> Label message = new Label("*Cay's message*");

as part of his class which extends the [Application Class](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/application/Application.html). He describes using a setScene as follows:

> stage.setScene(new Scene(message));

The result is a dialog box with the message.

Alternatively, the JavaFX 8 API describes [Class SwingNode](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html), which,

> is used to embed a Swing content into a JavaFX application