# JavaFX dialog Box

Tags: java, dialog

```
public void exitGame() { //pop up dialogue
    Platform.exit();
}
```

I've tried a lot of different things I've seen on the internet but I can't get anything to work. All I need is a simple dialog box that pops up when you hit the Exit button in the menu and asks "Are you sure you want to exit?" and offers a working "Yes, I'm sure." and "No, cancel" button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and show common dialog (Error, Warning, Confirmation) in JavaFX 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309981/how-to-create-and-show-common-dialog-error-warning-confirmation-in-javafx-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the sample for JavaFX dialog. There is no dialog api in JavaFx 2.x. So you have create your own stage and create components in it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @author JayaPrasad
 * 
 */
public class SampleDialog extends Application {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFx Dialog");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Click me to display popup dialog");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                final Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
                dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

                Label exitLabel = new Label("Are you sure you want to exit?");
                exitLabel.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

                Button yesBtn = new Button("Yes");
                yesBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        dialogStage.close();

                    }
                });
                Button noBtn = new Button("No");

                noBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        dialogStage.close();

                    }
                });

                HBox hBox = new HBox();
                hBox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
                hBox.setSpacing(40.0);
                hBox.getChildren().addAll(yesBtn, noBtn);

                VBox vBox = new VBox();
                vBox.setSpacing(40.0);
                vBox.getChildren().addAll(exitLabel, hBox);

                dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
                dialogStage.show();
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are nice too:

```
  yesBtn.setOnAction (e -> dialogStage.close ());
  noBtn.setOnAction (e -> dialogStage.close ());
```

Also APPLICATION_MODAL is probably what you want:

```
  dialogStage.initModality (Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```