# JavaFx equivalent of Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jframe

I am learning JavaFX. I have encountered a problem; I cannot figure out what is the equivalent of a Swing JFrame in JavaFX. Is it the Scene or the Stage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equivalent of a Swing `JFrame` in JavaFX is the [Stage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html) class which extends from [Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html) and can be made visible by calling [show()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#show--) method. The [Scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) is more like the frame's content pane (not *exactly* the same but similar in concept).

#### Off-topic

For details on components similar to `JDialog` have a read to this Marco Jakob's post: [JavaFX Dialogs (official)](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

On the other hand there are third-party options available such as [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) and Marco Jakob's [JavaFX dialogs](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-dialogs/), or we can play with stage's [Modality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html) to achieve something close as exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310446/1795530).