# Why am I unable to programmatically close a Dialog on JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

This sample of code shows but doesn't close a javafx.scene.control.Dialog on JavaFx:

```
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<Void>();
dialog.show();
dialog.close();
```

or

```
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<Void>();
dialog.show();
dialog.hide();
```

Why?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Since Dialog is from java and not from javafx. The Dialog class in java does not have a close() function. If you want to know more about java awt dialog, please check out this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html and for javafx http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm

Comment: Also this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309981/how-to-create-and-show-common-dialog-error-warning-confirmation-in-javafx-2 should give you some information about javafx dialogs.

Comment: @WonderWorld I'm using javafx.scene.control.Dialog from JavaFX not the dialog class from Java. But thank you anyway.

Comment: You must be using some other version of javafx than the latest i assume, because the javafx i have installed does not have javafx.scene.control.Dialog.

Comment: [`Dialog`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/index.html?javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) was introduced in JavaFX 8u40 (at the time of writing this is still about 3 weeks from GA release).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the javadoc:

> More often than not, dialogs are shown in a modal and blocking fashion. 'Modal' means that the dialog prevents user interaction with the owning application whilst it is showing, and 'blocking' means that **code execution stops at the point in which the dialog is shown**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Means that `dialog.close()` is called after your modal is closed already.

Comment: @WonderWorld Why disabled? The docs say code is blocked while it is "showing", i.e. until it is closed.

Comment: I read JB Nizet his answer as if you have a button in your main application that pops up a new dialog when you press it, while that dialog is showing the main application is inaccesible aka disabled (Modal). Or im understanding this all wrong.

Comment: Well, that's true but it's slightly different to what the question (and answer) are about. This is about *code execution blocking* while the dialog is showing, not about access to the other windows in the application.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. What he means by this answer is that the OP his code that he is showing must be somewhere in the main application because he creates a new dialog. So if the new dialog is shown in blocking fashion then the dialog.close() wouldn't work because code execution is blocked.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it is blocked until the dialog is **closed** (as @atamanroman says), not until (as your comment says) the dialog is **disabled**. (Maybe you didn't intend your comment to say that, but in context it is clearly how anyone would interpret it.) I think you probably just misread the original comment.

Comment: @James_D I do `dialog.close()`in a JavaFX Task `setOnSucceeded`method, but the dialog is not closed. So it's not clear to me, how to achieve to close the dialog.
How to close a dialog that is shown by `dialog.showandwait()` programmatically and return control to the "main app"?

Comment: @marc Post a new question with a [MCVE]. Do you really need `showAndWait()`: why wouldn't just `show()` work for you?

Comment: Unless the api changed between the beginning and end of 2015, note that show() does not block.  showAndWait() does.

Comment: This does not deal with the issue mentioned in the question. The java docs also states "To specify whether you want blocking or non-blocking dialogs, developers simply choose to call Dialog.showAndWait() or Dialog.show() (respectively)".

Answer (score 32):

I'm not sure why the response above has been marked as an answer as it clearly doesn't answer the question. The underlying issue appears to be that it is not possible to programmatically close a dialog box that doesn't have a Close/Cancel button:

Dialog box opens, but doesn't close:

```
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<Void>();
dialog.show();
dialog.close();
```

To close, add a cancel button to it just before you close it:

```
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<Void>();
dialog.show();
// Add dummy cancel button
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.CANCEL);
// Dialog will now close
dialog.close();
```

Comment: Well that design decision makes no sense at all. Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Dialog<Boolean> and setResult(true) before close() will do the trick

Comment: Thanx for those answers. I don't get the idea of this frustrating design, but it is what we have to live with. I have implemented a method closeFoo() ... :D

Answer (score 19):

A shorter (but not less "hacky" method) is to use a dialog of a specific type (other than Void) and set a (arbitrary) result directly before hiding it, e.g.:

```
Dialog<Boolean> dialog = new Dialog<Boolean>();
dialog.show();
...
// for closing
dialog.setResult(Boolean.TRUE);
dialog.close();
```

Comment: Not "hacky" at all. For me is the best response !

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you should add button

```java
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<Void>();
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);
dialog.showAndWait();
```

if that design makes no sense at all you can hide button

```java
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<Void>();
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CLOSE);

Node closeButton = dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CLOSE);
closeButton.setVisible(false);

dialog.showAndWait();
```

also you can use directly window

```java
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<Void>();

Window window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
window.setOnCloseRequest((e) -> {
    dialog.hide();
});

dialog.showAndWait();
```

last solution is create your own dialog window

```java
Stage dialog = new Stage();
dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
dialog.setResizable(false);

VBox root = new VBox();
Scene dialogScene = new Scene(root);

Button close = new Button("Close");
close.setOnAction((e) -> {
    dialog.close();
});

root.getChildren().addAll(close);
dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
dialog.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Vivid! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
dialog.hide();
dialog.close();
```

**Advice:** The `hide()` method is in `Dialog` but not in `Alert`

Answer (score 0):

You can close the dialog by accessing the window its `DialogPane` is embedded in:

```
Window window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
window.setOnCloseRequest(event -> dialog.close());
```

Now the dialog should close like every other window.