# JavaFX working with threads and GUI

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, javafx, task

I have a problem while working with JavaFX and Threads. Basically I have two options: working with `Tasks` or `Platform.runLater`. As I understand `Platform.runLater` should be used for simple/short tasks, and `Task` for the longer ones. However, I cannot use any of them.

When I call `Thread`, it has to pop up a captcha dialog in a middle of task. While using `Task`, it ignores my request to show new dialog... It does not let me to create a new stage.

On the other hand, when I use `Platform.runLater`, it lets me show a dialog, however, the program's main window freezes until the pop up dialog is showed.

I need any kind of solution for this. If anyone knows how to deal with this or had some similar experience and found a solution I am looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX2: Can I pause a background Task / Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941084/javafx2-can-i-pause-a-background-task-service)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As puce says, you have to use `Task` or `Service` for the things that you need to do in background. And `Platform.runLater` to do things in the JavaFX Application thread from the background thread.

You have to synchronize them, and one of the ways to do that is using the class `CountDownLatch`.

Here is an example:

```
Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {           
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    //Background work                       
                    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {                          
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                //FX Stuff done here
                            }finally{
                                latch.countDown();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    latch.await();                      
                    //Keep with the background work
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    service.start();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Thank you so much!

Comment: After looking at this answer closer, I have come to the conclusion that this is a terrible answer. I would recommend using `Service` or `Task` as they are designed. See https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

Answer (score 8):

Use a `Worker` (`Task`, `Service`) from the JavaFX Application thread if you want to do something in the background.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html

Use `Platform.runLater` from a background thread if you want to do something on the JavaFX Application thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: I create a Worker (Task). Once I need so show a pop up I call Platform.runLater however I need to wait for response (it is input dialog), but if I create new thread (Platform.runLater) it does not wait for respons and Worker continues... How to deal with it. Maybe there is a way to pause Worker thread wait for input from Platform.runLater and then continue...?

Answer (score 1):

It's too late to answer but for those who have the error, here is the solution XD

You can use one Thread.

Use the lambda expression for the `runnable` in the thread and the `runlater`.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        //Here write all actions that you want execute on background

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            //Here the actions that use the gui where is finished the actions on background.
        });
    });
t.start();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can user directly this code
Don't forget you can't send non-final variable in thread .
you can send final variable in thread

```
     //final String me="ddddd";
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    // me = me + "eee";
                    //...Your code....
              
            }
        }).start();
```

Use in

> your code

try/catch