# How to use JavaFx for GUI and PApplet for Output (in different windows)

Tags: javafx, processing

I'm working on an app that uses **JavaFX** as GUI to control a **PApplet** that runs in a different window.

I've managed to make the two things appear and work, but when I try to load files in the `PApplet` class, I get a warning that says `"The sketch path is not set"` and an error like this: `"java.lang.RuntimeException: Files must be loaded inside setup() or after it has been called."`

I'm guessing that I might not have initialized the PApplet properly.

**Here is my javafx.Application class**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("application.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Clusters");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("application.Controller");
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Here is my PApplet class**

```
public class Controller extends PApplet {

    private ArrayList<File> files;
    private ArrayList<PImage> images;

    public Controller() {
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(640, 360);
    }

    public void setup() {
        background(0);     
        images = new ArrayList<PImage>();
        files = new ArrayList<File>();
    }

    public void draw() {
    }

    public void importImages() {
        // Open File Chooser
        FileChooser dialog = new FileChooser();
        dialog.setTitle("Import Images");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image files (*.jpg, *.png, *.tiff)", "*.jpg", "*.png", "*.tiff");
        dialog.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        List<File> imported_files = dialog.showOpenMultipleDialog(new Stage());
        System.out.println(imported_files); 

        for (File f: imported_files) {
            images.add(loadImage(f.getAbsolutePath()));
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " loaded");
        }
    }
}
```

**This is how I link the importImages() method to the FXXML file**

```
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem fx:id="file_open" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="file_save" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="file_save_as" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="file_import" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#importImages" text="Import" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
```

Comment: How are you calling the `importImages()` function?

Comment: clicking a javafx menuItem which is linked to the method in the fxxml doc.
_<MenuItem fx:id="file_import" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#importAction" text="Import" />_

Comment: Just a guess, but this might be a threading issue? What happens if you call the `importImages()` function from a Processing function like `mousePressed()`?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Animation Thread

Comment: So i replaced the fx.FileChooser with a awt.FileDialog and when the method is called by the animation thread it works, but it doesn't when is called by the fx thread.

How would I call a certain method to be executed by a specific existing thread ?
(or how would i solve my problem with a workaround ?)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Processing functions like `loadImage()` need to be called from Processing's main thread, and JavaFX functions like `dialog.showOpenMultipleDialog()` need to be called from the JavaFX Application Thread.

Putting work on the JavaFX Application Thread is pretty straightforward. Read [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) and [JavaFX working with threads and GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16708931/873165) (or just google something like "JavaFX thread" for a ton of results). But basically you can call the `Platform.runLater()` function to put work on the JavaFX Application Thread.

Going the other way and putting work on the Processing thread is a bit more complicated. You can read more about concurrency [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

To test this theory, I'd do something simple like this:

```
public class Controller extends PApplet {
  boolean loadImages = false;
  // other variables you need to communicate between threads

  public void draw() {
    if(loadImages){
      // call loadImages()
      loadImages = false;
    }
  }

  // call this from JavaFX
  public void importImages() {
    // set other variables you need here
    loadImages = true;
  }
}
```

If this works, you can do something fancier like maintaining a queue of events.

Comment: I tried the queue solution, but it's not working cause there's an inconsistency between my PApplet window (created through PApplet.main("")) and the PApplet known by the Controller.

Comment: making the queue static works, but i'm worried that it could raise other problems in future development, what do you think ?

Comment: @LorenzoRivosecchi Without seeing the code it's hard to say. The pattern you're looking for is called [producer-consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). I'd recommend asking a follow-up question in a new post if you get stuck.