# Call a method of a controller from another controller JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a problem, i'm doing a program that simulates the FCFS algorithm. I'm working with threads. The thing is that when I press T the program needs to interrupt the thread and show a window(stage) with a table, when I close the stage i need to start again the thread, so my idea is that from the second controller call the function of the other controller and then close the stage
Here is where i call the second stage:

```
case T:
            banderaPause=true;
            th.interrupt();
            Stage stTableView = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane root = null;
            try {
                root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("showTable.fxml").openStream());
                showTableController stController = (showTableController)loader.getController();
                stController.init(arreglo);
                stTableView.setTitle("Programa 4");
                stTableView.setScene(new Scene(root, 950, 375));
                stTableView.setX(2.00);
                stTableView.setY(300.00);
                stTableView.show();
                stTableView.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("ya cerre");
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
```

And here is where i tried to call the method from the second controller:

```
case C:
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("second.fxml"));
                Parent  root = loader.load();
                Controller n = loader.getController();
                n.Continua();
                Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
```

But the stage just close and the method was never called

Comment: In addition to the issue addressed by @fabian's answer, the controller `n` is attached to a UI that you never display, so calling `n.Continua()` almost certainly does not do what you want it to do. (`n` is the wrong instance of `Controller`). Also see the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941084/javafx2-can-i-pause-a-background-task-service, which I think gives you a way to do exactly what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [javadoc for `onCloseRequested`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty--) (emphasis mine):

> Called when there is an **external request** to close this Window.

So the handler is not executed, if you call `close` yourself.

For `Stage`s that are not the primary stage there is an option to wait for the window to be closed, however: [`Stage.showAndWait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--), so you could use this instead of registering an event handler:

```
stTableView.showAndWait();

// Print to console after stage is closed
System.out.println("ya cerre");
```