# Java newbie coding. Adding a display message

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to java and I'm trying to create a currency converter right now.
I've made this little currency converter that converts Dollars into euros and pounds.
When ran, it pops up the java screen and you can enter the amount of dollars you would like to convert, and it will give you the amount of euros/pounds it would be.

Now i would like to display a little Jpannel message first.
I can't quite seem to figure out how.
Im sure its quite easy so forgive me for my newbieness. Help would be fantastic

Sorry if the layout of my question seems odd. im not familiar with this website yet. I will improve.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

I've made this so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class converter extends JFrame {

    private static final double DOLLAR_PER_EURO = 0.77;
    //private static final double   DOLLAR_PER_POUND = 0.66;

    private JTextField _dollarsTF = new JTextField(3);        
    private JTextField _eurosTF   = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField _poundsTF = new JTextField(3);

    public converter() {

        JButton convertBtn = new JButton("Convert");
        convertBtn.addActionListener(new ConvertBtnListener());

        _dollarsTF.addActionListener((ActionListener) new ConvertBtnListener());
        _eurosTF.setEditable(false);
        _poundsTF.setEditable(false);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();        
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  

        content.add(new JLabel("Enter amounts of dollars to compare: "));  
        content.add(_dollarsTF);              
        content.add(convertBtn);               
        content.add(new JLabel("Euros: "));
        content.add(_eurosTF);
     //   content.add(new JLabel("English Pounds: "));
     //   content.add(_poundsTF);
        setContentPane(content);       
        pack();                        
        setTitle("Currency converter");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
    }

    class ConvertBtnListener implements ActionListener {       
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String dyStr = _dollarsTF.getText();          
            int Dollars = Integer.parseInt(dyStr);                 
            double Euros = Dollars * DOLLAR_PER_EURO;
            //double Pounds = Dollars * DOLLAR_PER_POUND;
            _eurosTF.setText("" + Euros);
            // _poundsTF.setText("" + Pounds);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {                    
        converter window = new converter();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080205/popup-message-boxes

Comment: So you're saying you want a JPanel to pop up with the converted value in it, or you want a message to appear before anything happens?

Comment: I would like to display a message before anything happens.

Comment: java convention: write the first letter of a class as a capital letter ;-)

Comment: Will do in the future ^^ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, I understand what you mean. Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow and the question formatting was fine! I'm glad to see you're showing that you've made an effort.

Now it seems to me you just want a little message to pop up. It seems pointless, to me, to write all the JPanel code to appear, when Swing has a lovely Class called `JOptionPane` to do those sorts of things for you. [Here is the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

The syntax is quite simple, for what you want.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("This is your message", parentObject);
```

This will make a small dialog box appear with your chosen message in it. The `parentObject` field is the container that is showing this dialog. In your case, it is the `converter` class (Should really be `Converter`). That is because `converter` extends JFrame. So your code would be:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("This is your message", this);
```

Comment: Ah sorry i actually meant JOptionpane and i am trying to use that right now, thanks alot for the answer i will try to apply it :)

Comment: I believe your code would work if i knew where to put it (forgive my newbieness again haha)

Do i simply make a method for it outside the public converter() { ?
Or do i put it in?

Comment: Do you want it to appear as soon as the program starts?

Comment: Yes, i would like to display a little message when i run my code.
After the message would appear, the actual converter would start.

Comment: So then you want to plug my code at the very start of your program, perhaps at the start of the `converter` constructor :)

Comment: Thanks it works now :) One last question: how do i mark this as the right answer? haha

Comment: hahah. There's an empty tick next to the rating next to my answer. Click that and it will mark it as correct :)

Comment: Thank you once again :) you've been a great help

Comment: My pleasure. Don't hesitate to ask any more questions!