# how can i display a message dialog box in java

Tags: java

i want to display a message dialog box in java. At this moment i can only display a message in a console by using `System.out.println()` method

Example :

```
public class demo{
        public static void main(String[] x){
           // i want to display the below message in a dialog box
           System.out.print("java is fun"); 

         }
      }
```

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"hi");`

Comment: thanks Pavneet, i works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popup Message boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080205/popup-message-boxes)

Answer (score 9):

use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` method and you can define some or all the arguments of the method

Code example :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // import javax packages
public class demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // using showMessageDialog(component parentComponent,String message,String messageTitle,int optionType) method to display a message dialog box
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"java is fun","Title",1);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use this code

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "java is fun");
```